# css layout issue in some case when long text is beside some image

Tags: css, layout, css-float

I'm writting an opesource filemanager in c++ (with css stylesheet) who can be accessed trough a web browser.

I have a layout problem when long text is beside some icons :
[image] 
the same image with more colors (for helping to read the stylesheet) :
[image]
revelant css code :

```
.rowLayout{ /* the gray row */
display: table;
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
    width:100hw;
    min-width:100hw;
    max-width:100hw;
}

.rowLayout img { /* icon */
    display: table-row; 
    background: #ff0000; 
    max-width: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
    min-width: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 67%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(67%);
    transform: translateX(67%)
}

.img-txt { /* the text beside the icon */
    background-color: #ffaaaa; 
    display: table-row;
    text-align: center;
    max-width:120px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    position:absolute;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.contentLayout { /* rows container */
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden; 
    overflow-y: auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #c4c1bd;
    width: calc(100% - 30px) 
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
    min-height: 50px; /* do not touch me */
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* special item, stretch through the code to avoid the icons evenly positioned */
.unusedSpace-box{
    width:0;
    min-width:0;
    max-width:0;
    height:0;
    min-height:0;
    max-height:0;
}
```

if you check `.img-txt` you'll see I should have some pink color somewhere. That color disapear when I add to much rows. For example with less rows :
[image]
in blue is what I want, the red arrows on the last picture means I want to paste at the top of the div.
Since the code is generated via C++, I don't have html but the one I can see from firefox :
[image]
*n.b. : the `<p></p>`are irrevelant, they should not be there it was a try. There or not, that changes nothing.*

if anything else would be revelant, just tell.